# Startup Project - Blazor with SignalR. Server/Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr, blazor

I wanted to get starting with .NET blazor and SignalR. I started this simple SignalR Blazor application as a tutorial. I found this [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sHsOJ02sXyY).  I have gone through this example step by step a few times and I must be over looking something.  I am running both of these on .Net Core 3.1 on visual studio 19.  The server is the startup project but when I run the project the index.razor does not get called.  I put in the proper endpoints a the demo.  But I can't hit any of the pages on the client.  I spent hours and hours on this and appreciate any help.

endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

**This is My Server Hub Class**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using SignalRTCBlazor.Shared.Models;
using System.Text.Json;


namespace SignalRTCBlazor.Server.Hubs
{
public class ChatHub : Hub
{

    public async Task NewUser(string username)
    {
        var userInfo = new UserInfo() { userName = username, connectionId = Context.ConnectionId };
        await Clients.Others.SendAsync("NewUserArrived", JsonSerializer.Serialize(userInfo));
    }

    public async Task HelloUser(string userName, string user)
    {
        var userInfo = new UserInfo() { userName = userName, connectionId = Context.ConnectionId };
        await Clients.Client(user).SendAsync("UserSaidHello", JsonSerializer.Serialize(userInfo));
    }

    public async Task SendSignal(string signal, string user)
    {
        await Clients.Client(user).SendAsync("SendSignal", Context.ConnectionId, signal);
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }

    public Task SendMessageToCaller(string message)
    {
        return Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }

    public Task SendMessageToGroup(string message)
    {
        return Clients.Group("SignalR Users").SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(System.Exception exception)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("UserDisconnect", Context.ConnectionId);
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
}
```

**This is the Server Startup**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using SignalRTCBlazor.Server.Hubs;
namespace SignalRTCBlazor.Server
{
 public class Startup
 {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddSignalR();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
        });
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  So many settings and I am still learning.   The example says to put the following lines in code.

```
   endpoints.MapHub<Hubs.ChatHub>(ChatClient.HUBURL);
   endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
```

**and to remove**

```
     endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
     endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
```

**What I did was put the other two lines in and it works**

```
      endpoints.MapHub<Hubs.ChatHub>(ChatClient.HUBURL);
      endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
      endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
```

Answer (score -1):

First in your Startup.cs under the ConfigureServices add the middleware like this:

```
services.AddSignalR();
```

Then under the Configure, you define the route to your hub like this :

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
   {
    endpoints.MapHub<Noty>("/notifyHub");
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    ...
   });
```

You need to write your Hub class, Something like this, the hub has a SetMessage method that will invoke later:

```
 public class Noty : Hub
    {
      private static IHubContext<Noty> _hubContext;

      public Noty(IHubContext<Noty> hubContext)
      {
          _hubContext = hubContext;
      }
      private async static Task SetMessage(string message)
      {
        await _hubContext.Clients.User(State.User.Current.Id).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
      }
    }
```

Finally, write the connection script (inside a .js file and reference it in your _Host.cshtml file)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/notifyHub").build();
        connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (message{      
            alert(message);
        });
    });
```

Now you can call SendMessage from your hub everywhere you want and the hub alerts the message.

Comment: I have all of that like the example video.                  endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

Comment: try the code that I have explained, it works, then you can customize it.

Comment: look at this example in the microsoft docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor-webassembly?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I have all of that I posted my Server code and startup.  I followed the example.

Comment: It seems that  you have a problem in you javascript code.

Comment: If you watch the video and example it is all blazor C# no javascript.